# Calling a click event containing a delegate stops the application from starting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, delegates

I have a refresh button on my `user control` that works just fine every time I click on it. This is the code to its click event:

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!RefreshFolder())
    {
        Notify(new string[] { "Refresh failed." });
    }
    else
    {
        Notify(new string[] { "Refreshed." });
    }

}
```

Notify function happens to be a delegate call from my main form. This function works well when called normally. What I want to do is to raise the above event when my user control is loaded. But when I call `btnRefresh.PerformClick()`  on the load event the application does not start and quits automatically after a short while. But when instead of the `Notify` function I put a `MessageBox.Show("blah")` the function works properly.

This is the delegate I use:

```
public delegate void NotifyMe(string[] messages);
```

And on my main form I have the following line in its constructor so that my user control can use the Notify function of the main control:

```
userctrlSelectManualCampaignFile.Notify += new NotifyMe(Notify);
```

The function works perfectly well as I said unless when I try to raise the click event. Any ideas?

**Update:**
Main form constructor:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    logger = new Logger();
    connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
    datetimeHelper = new DateTimeHelper();
    userctrlSettingsGeneral.Notify += new NotifyMe(Notify);
    userctrlSelectManualCampaignFile.Notify += new NotifyMe(Notify);
}
```

My user control constructor:

```
public ManualCampaignFiles()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Show constructor of the form

Comment: @T.S. updated with main form and user control constructor.

Comment: What if instead `btnRefresh.PerformClick()` you just call `btnRefresh_Click`? Also, this is little confusing. You have `userctrlSettingsGeneral.Notify += new NotifyMe(Notify);`. Basically, you want to achieve callback effect. You should have `private notifyMe _callback;` in your control. And then do `if (_callback != null) _callback();

Comment: Running this on the 64-bit version of Windows 7?  It has a bug that causes exceptions to be swallowed when you debug a program that's forced to run in 32-bit mode.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably causing a "silent" exception to be thrown, causing your application to quit.

Such exceptions can be "swallowed" by the framework, for example within event handlers.

Try setting your debug environment to break on thrown exceptions. For this, go to the Debug > Exceptions... menu, then in the dialog that shows up, make sure to check the "Thrown" checkbox corresponding to Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

This way, when you lauch your program, it will break at the moment an exception is thrown, allowing you to figure out what is going on.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [in another forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39c71d71-4bd5-4975-aed8-1dfdf8be6226/as-an-event-throw-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object?forum=csharplanguage):

> Before event raising you should check if event is not null. This is
> common pattern for event raising.

Answer provided by Vitaliy Liptchinsky.

But Hans Passant's answer was also very close to truth.